# WebAudio activeSourceCount

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-audio-api

Here's my code:

`var ac = new webkitAudioContext();`

On pressing the play button:

```
var source = ac.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = audioTrackBuffer;
source.connect(ac.destination);
source.noteOn(0);
```

On pressing the stop button:

```
source.noteOff(0);
source.disconnect();
```

Each time I press the play button `ac.activeSourceCount` increments.

Why doesn't `activeSourceCount` decrement when I `noteOff()` and `disconnect()` the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was removed from the spec: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/rev/cfe4ae147c64

Relevant discussion here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-audio/2013AprJun/0308.html

Basically, since they added the "ended" event, I think the idea is that you can keep track of this yourself now.

Comment: Yep.  This will get removed from Blink soon.